# How to customize the checkbox , add a background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to convert the default checkbox to this

[image]

It's ok to use anything, A background image, CSS3, jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/uGYv6/

Comment: A check box usually has at least two visual states (four if you take its `enabled` attribute into account), but you're only showing one. How do you intend to differentiate the checked state from the unchecked state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not against using an existing toolkit, [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox) can turn check boxes into custom-styled buttons that support the four basic visual states (plus one more hover state):

[image: jQuery UI buttons from check boxes]

However, to be able to use that feature the way you want (using the `value` attribute as the label), you'll have to give `id` attributes to your check boxes, and add `<label>` elements that refer to these ids and expose their check box's value as their inner text. You can either change your markup by hand:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nutri" name="nutri" value="select">
<label for="nutri">select</label>
```

Or modify it dynamically:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(index) {
    $("<label>").text(this.value)
                .attr("for", this.id = "checkbox" + index + 1)
                .insertAfter(this);
});
```

From there on, it's as simple as calling `button()` on the check box or `buttonset()` on a container. Of course, if none of the default jQuery UI themes are appropriate for your project, you can design your own style for each visual state with [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

You can find a live demo in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbHXX/2/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use pure css. Just add a label after your checkbox:

```
#check_box {

    display:none;

}

#check_box + label{

    background:url('images/check-box.png') no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}


#check_box:checked + label{

    background:url('images/check-box-checked.png') no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;

}
```

Comment: How can you do this but have the label before the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourCheckbox').hide().after($('<img/>', { src: 'blah.png', alt: 'whatever' }).click(function(){
    $(this).prev('input:checkbox').click();
}));
```

You could probably also create a label containing an image. Then you could get rid of the `click()` handler.

Comment: Yes. You could have tested without the `.hide()`. You should improve the code to show both unchecked and checked state though.

Comment: Can we change image after selected like @Frédéric Hamidi commented. I mean if user uncheck again then I want to show a different image