# How to Apply background image on the checkbox

Tags: css

how do I apply background image on the checkbox.I know this is something which is very easy but still I am finding it difficult 
here is my HTML code . I don't know what is the issue in this

```
    <div>
<style>
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    background: transparent url("http://ilexsquare.com/finalhot/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/hotlogo-2.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
</style>
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

please Help

Comment: Possible dublicate of [How to customize the checkbox , add a background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639328/how-to-customize-the-checkbox-add-a-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

Julian Be is correct you can't apply background images directly to checkboxes.

The only way to achieve this is to spoof the result. You could do this by having a `<label>` wrapped around the checkbox with it's `overflow` set to `hidden` and then move the checkbox itself into the overflow. This way ensures the checkbox is still clickable but not visible to the user. You can then add a `<span>` after the checkbox and apply the background image to this element depending on the state of the checkbox using the `:checked` selector and `+` selector.

Something like this

```
  /* Set overflow of label to hidden so the checkbox can disappear */
  .label-with-hidden-checkbox {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  /* Move the checkbox out of view */
  .label-with-hidden-checkbox .hidden-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  /* Set the background image of the spoof checkbox to the unchecked state */
  .label-with-hidden-checkbox .hidden-checkbox + .spoof-checkbox{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: transparent url("unchecked-state-image.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  }

  /* When the checkbox is checked set the background image of the spoof checkbox to the checked state */
  .label-with-hidden-checkbox .hidden-checkbox:checked + .spoof-checkbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: transparent url("checked-state-image.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  }

  </style>
  <label class="label-with-hidden-checkbox">
    <input class="hidden-checkbox" type="checkbox" /><span class="spoof-checkbox"></span> This is a checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use label to apply the image here is the jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ce9kn0e/2/)
this is your HTML code:

```
    <input type="checkbox" />
<label></label>
```

and CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0px;
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
label{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
label:before{
  content:"";
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
border-radius: 2.5px;
background:  url("http://ilexsquare.com/finalhot/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/hotlogo-2.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add images to checkboxes.

Comment: I think you understood the question wrong, he wants that an image will be shown after you click the checkbox...

Comment: Oh, sorry,i understand it like she wants to add images to checkboxes